# Expressions/operator precedence in Amend At and in function parameters

Tags: kdb, k

I always thought that in `q` and in `k` all expressions divided `;` evaluated left-to-right and operator precedence inside is right-to-left.

But then I tried to apply this principle to Ament At operator parameters. Confusingly it seems working in the opposite direction:

```
$ q KDB+ 3.6 2019.04.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems
q)@[10 20 30;g;:;100+g:1]
10 101 30
```

The same precedence works inside a function parameters too:

```
q){x+y}[q;10+q:100]
210
```

So why does it happend - why does it first calculate the last one parameter and only then first? Is it a feature we should avoid?

**Upd**: evaluation vs parsing.
There could be another cases: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#when-e-is-not-a-function

```
q)@[2+;"42";{)}]
')
  [0]  @[2+;"42";{)}]
q)@[string;42;a:100] / expression not a function
"42"
q)a // but a was assigned anyway
100
q)@[string;42;{b::99}] / expression is a function
"42"
q)b // not evaluated
'b
  [0]  b
       ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon is a multi-purpose separator in q. It can separate statements (e.g. `a:10; b:20`), in which case statements are evaluated from **left-to-right** similar to many other languages. But when it separates elements of a list it creates a *list expression* which (an expression) is evaluated from **right-to-left** as any other q expression would be.

Like in this example:

```
q)(q;10+q:100)
110 100
```

One of many overloads of the dot operator (`.`) evaluates its left operand on a list of values in its right operand:

```
q){x+y} . (q;10+q:100)
210
```

In order to do so a list expression itself needs to be evaluated first, and it will be, from right-to-left as any other list expression.

However, the latter is just another way of getting the result of

```
{x+y}[q;10+q:100]
```

which therefore should produce the same value. And it does. By evaluating function arguments from **right-to-left**, of course!

A side note. Please don't be confused by the conditional evaluation *statement* `$[a;b;c]`. Even though it looks like an expression it is in fact a statement which evaluates `a` first and only then either `b` or `c`. In other words `a`, `b` and `c` are not arguments of some function `$` in this case.

Comment: Igor, thank you very much! What a language, how nicely it reuses its concepts, list creation for passing function arguments.

Comment: I've met functions, lambdas, operators, iterators, projections, compositions and derived functions - types [100–112]. What kind of objects have the same evaluation order as `$` has? Is it only `$` who has left-to-right evaluation rules?

Comment: @egor7 `$`, `if`, `do` and `while`: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#conditional-evaluation-and-control-statements. The last three are called control words. They are somewhat special, e.g. `type while` won't work.

Comment: Evaluation vs parsing brings something to the table too